# Expect take first prompt after spawn

Tags: regex, bash, shell, expect

I want to make a script that it take as `expect` first promt after `spawn "ssh user@server"`.

Am example:

I have 5 servers but all differs the initial promt and i can't modify:

```
[root@test home]#
root@server2:~$
User: root Server: server3 ~ !
```

You got the point.

This is how i think but i can't figure out how to get that

```
    set timeout -1
    spawn "ssh root@server"

    expect "assword:"
    send "password\n"

#
    var=getpromt
#   
    expect "$var"
    send "stuff\n"

    expect eof
```

How can i get those promts to a expect script that can recognize that is the promt to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just keep an array of regular expressions:

```tcl
array set prompt_re {
    test    {#\s*$}
    server2 {$\s*$}
    server3 {!\s*$}
}

spawn ssh $user@$host

expect assword:
send "$password\r"

expect -re $prompt_re($host)
```

Or, you could mash those up into a single regex

```tcl
expect -re {[#$!]\s*$}   ;# expect the prompt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pseudo code):

```
echo commands-to-be-executed-on-ssh | expect-script
```

& your expect-script would looks something like:

```
set timeout -1
spawn "ssh root@server"

expect "assword:"
send "password\n"
interact # <~~~~~~~~~~~ At this point, expect would pass the redirected/piped stdin to ssh process.
```

Note: I haven't tested this. So apologies for any syntax errors :)

Comment: I want to make it dynamically, the script will be used by some ppl that don't know linux commands.

Comment: if the command to be executed on remote terminal, is constant, you can easily write a bash wrapper around the expect script, right?